# Microphone volume gets low after while

Tags: windows, usb, audio, microphone

The volume on my USB microphone (Sennheiser pc363d) gets really low after a random time interval. (My friends on skype says the volume on my mic is so low you can barely hear it, although it isn't completely gone).

Sometimes it takes 10 minutes, sometimes 2 hours for the "bug" to happen. A fix is to go in to recording devices and disable and re enabling the microphone device. This only fixes it temporarily. I have tried at least 10 different Sennheiser drivers and I still have the same problem. I'm using windows 8.1.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and reword the "gets really low" part? As it is written now, it could be physically moving, or low volume, or other things.

Comment: @LPChip Edited...

Comment: I confirm that this problem exactly as described definitely exists for some other users as well. Same model of headset.

Comment: @Peter i fixed it by not letting Skype adjust my microphone volume inside of the Skype settings